# is it elegant to continue do connect() if connect() fails or accept() if accept() fails

Tags: networking, network-programming

when using connect() in a tcp client program or accept() in a tcp server program
many possible exceptions may happen
e.g, TCP SYN or TCP SYN/ACK is lost OR some other errors

(BTW, I'm wondering ,if TCP SYN is lots, will connect() retransmit TCP SYN or it just produces an error?)

ususally the source codes are like

```
if(connect()<0){
 ...
 exit(1);
}
```

or

```
if (accept()<)){
 ...
 exit(1);
}
```

however, if I want to try connect() or accept() again,
is it possible or not?
like

```
while(connect()<0){
       continue;
}
```

or

```
while(accept()<0){
      continue;
}
```

will such a dealing produce unacceptable consequences?

besides, how about send() and recv()
thanks!

Comment: Elegance has nothing to do with it. The question, what is your functional requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Generally once and `accept` or `connect` fails, they will always fail, so your while loops are just infinite loop on failure.  There are some exceptions (non-blocking sockets that 'fail' with EINPROGRESS or EAGAIN), but generally when there's an error, you need to check the error code and do something appropriate, such as closing the socket and opening a new one.

Comment: how about the case of lost TCP SYN, will connect() function retransmit?

Comment: No. `connect()` failure does not mean a single `SYN` packet timed out.  `connect()` failure means that *all* retransmissions of that packet failed.  You don't need to write any code to make the platform TCP stack simply do its job.

Comment: then how about send() recv(), fork()failure? if they failed, it means I need to close this socket or quit the program?